# Dividing tuples in a series

Tags: pandas, tuples, series

How do I divide a panda series:

```
d = {'a': ('a','ball'), 'b': ('b','cat'), 'c': ('c','plane')}
ser = pd.Series(data=d, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
ser

a     (a, ball)
b      (b, cat)
c    (c, plane)
dtype: object
```

Into a pandas dataframe like:

```
Index Value
a     ball
b     cat
c     plane
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str[1]` with [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) if need one column `DataFrame`:

```
ser.str[1].to_frame('Value')
```

Or if need 2 columns `DataFrame`:

```
ser.str[1].rename_axis('Index').reset_index(name='Value')
```